# How to send an ajax contact form with to a recipient email address

Tags: ajax, reactjs, contact-form

I've currently got this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/some/url',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  success: function(data) {
  if (window.confirm('Thank you for your message. Can I erase the form?')) {
   document.querySelector('.form-input').val('');
  }
},
error: function(xhr, status, err) {
  console.error(status, err.toString());
  alert('There was some problem with sending your message.');
}
});
```

Instead of it going to a URL, how can I change it to send directly to a specific email address? I am using this contact form with a React app I've created.

Comment: can you please post your backend code where url points to ?

Comment: It doesn't point to anything right now, not sure whats the best way to do this with React. I just want it to send to one email address.

Comment: First you are using jquey ajax which is not best practice for react. 
Second I wanted to show you how to send it with your backend so you will make ajax request for some url and when url is "executed" mail will be sent.

Comment: Do you have any examples I can look at? Happy to try your method please! @KondukterCRO

Comment: No problem. Later I will post you example of react component that make axios call to backend api. Is php ok language for your backend that sends mail ?

Comment: Is there anyway to make it more React friendly, as not sure php is going to be suitable? It's already throwing errors.

Comment: Well with this approach you create form with fields in react and when you submit it data are going to be send to php which will send email.
This is 100% react way. React is handling frontend changes and at the end it will get response from backend is message sent. This part of code is not copy-paste. You need to adapt it to work with your project. You need to import axios and some php mailer (e.g. swift mailer). If you want to send message only with react it's not react friendly and I even think it's not possible without some server side processing.  What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

So react component, class based.

```
class Foo extends Component {
    popupQuestion() {
        // implement method
    }
    sendEmail() = () => {
        axios.post('/some/url', {
            subject: 'mail',
            to: 'someone@example.com',
            body: 'something',
            name: 'name'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            popupQuestion();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return 'Error occurred. Please refresh page and try again.';
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
           <form onSubmit={this.sendEmail}>
               // ...
           </form>
        );
    }
}
```

And php method that will be executed on some/url

```
public function sendEmailAction(): bool
{
    $request = // get request;
    $subject = $request->get('subject');
    $to = $request->get('to');
    $body = $request->get('body');
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.example.org', 25))
        ->setUsername('your username')
        ->setPassword('your password');
    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
    $message = (new Swift_Message($subject))
        ->setFrom(['mymail@exmaple.com' => 'me'])
        ->setTo([$to => $name])
        ->setBody($body);
    $sent = $mailer->send($message);
    return $sent ? true : false;
}
```